# Dagger2 : cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using Android Dagger2 but I am getting the error below.

My Module class:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private final App mApp;

    public ApplicationModule(App app) {
        this.mApp = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ContextType("Application")
    App provideApplicationContext(){
        return mApp;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    P2PService provideP2PService(App context){
        return new P2PService(context);
    }
}
```

My component class:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    @ContextType("Application")
    App getContext();

    P2PService p2pService();
}
```

The complied, Error message:

```
Error:(21, 16) error: com.sen5.smartlifebox.App cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
com.sen5.smartlifebox.App is injected at
com.sen5.smartlifebox.di.module.ApplicationModule.provideP2PService(context)
com.sen5.smartlifebox.data.p2p.P2PService is provided at
com.sen5.smartlifebox.di.component.ApplicationComponent.p2pService()
```

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What is  `@ContextType("Application")`?

Answer (score 1):

Dagger is telling you that it doesn't know how to provide the `App` dependency in your `provideP2PService` method.

You have to add `@ContextType("Application")` to the method's parameter like so:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
P2PService provideP2PService(@ContextType("Application") App context) {
    return new P2PService(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I am really confused by **@ContextType("Application")** in your code!

By the way, make these changes to your code and it will work:

**ApplicationModule.java**:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private final App mApp;

    public ApplicationModule(App app) {
        this.mApp = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    App provideApplicationContext(){
        return mApp;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    P2PService provideP2PService(App context){
        return new P2PService(context);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent.java**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

}
```

and this is how you can use this injection:

**App.java**:

```
public class App extends Application {

    ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return applicationComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this)).build();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    P2PService p2PService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        App app = (App) getApplication();
        app.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

For more references, you can take a look at this sample repo which contains an Android application developed using Dagger, MVP, RxJava and other useful libraries:

> http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers

I hope it helps :)